# how to speed up "Looking for reference(s)" in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

HI!!!!!

every time I change the name of a control there is this dialog that appears that is looking for references... it takes forever (sometimes) is there a way to speed it up I don't want to disable it cuz it's a cool feature that it looks for references but it sure takes lots of time... thanks

Comment: no answer yet.... sad =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved in Visual Studio 2010. I recommend you to upgrade to Visual Studio 2010. By the way, you can keep your project's version in 2008 while working with VS2010 IDE.

Answer (score 0):

It is known bug, there is no easy way to fix it. But you can buy an SSD to reduce access time to GAC, or uprgade to **VS 2010**.